# Port "COM X" does not exist - is something related to C# program or Machine limitation?

Tags: c#

I am a linux programmer venturing into the world of C# programming using windows. I have got a virtual machine( Oracle Virtual box) which runs windows 7. I have checked the ports and it says - COM 1, COM2, etc.However, It seems like my machine doesn't recognise COM1
Here are the errors I get.

What I want to know here is that is it something with my program liking missing some extra API or is it related to my machine capability?

```
System.IO.IOException: The port 'COM1' does not exist.
       at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
       at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor(String portName, Int32 baudRate, Parity
     parity, Int32 dataBits, StopBits stopBits, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeou
    t, Handshake handshake, Boolean dtrEnable, Boolean rtsEnable, Boolean discardNul
    l, Byte parityReplace)
       at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open()
       at EFTPOS_SHIM_APP.SerialPortMessenger.SerialPortMessengerStart() in C:\Users
    \shreyas\Dropbox\POS_SHIM_EFTPOS_APP\EFTPOS_SHIM_APP\EFTPOS_SHIM_APP\SerialPortM
    essenger.cs:line 31
```

Here is the code -

```
class SerialPortMessenger
    {
        private SerialPort port;


        public void SerialPortMessengerStart()
        {

            Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames());

            port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                 // attach a method to be called when there is data coming on to the port's buffer

            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(portDataReceivedHandler);

            // Begin Communication

            try
            {

                port.Open();
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Application.Run();

        }

        private void portDataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(port.ReadExisting());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm slightly concerned that this question is tagged [tag:asp.net] and you're talking about COM ports - so just to check, you're aware that this code will be trying to talk to COM ports on the *server* rather than on whatever machine the *browser* is running on?

Comment: corrected the tags. I am now trying to move from Linux to Windows programming so I might ask some questions which may be a bit basic. I have reworded my question so that my question can be helpful to others also.

Comment: Not all computers *have* the COM1 port, the first serial port, assuming the computer have one, may have a different starting number. Use `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` to get a list of the ports available on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your machine does not have a "COM1"? You can use the following code from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx to check available COM ports:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace SerialPortExample
{
    class SerialPortExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Get a list of serial port names.
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            Console.WriteLine("The following serial ports were found:");

            // Display each port name to the console.
            foreach(string port in ports)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(port);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can just inspect your computer's Device Manager under "Ports (COM & LPT)" to see available ports on your machine.

You can edit the following line:

```
port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
```

and change the "COM1", to whatever your comport number is. In the long run it would be best to store the COMx value in a settings file, since it will change from machine to machine.

**Edit:**

You mentioned that you are running on a virtual machine. Have you correctly added COM ports to the virtual machine? See this article: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=26860 on "How to: Add a Serial Port in Windows XP and 7 Guest."